# IPN transactions all INVALID

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

We've had our system setup with PayPal IPN (ssl) for about a decade.

Last night, all of our transactions starting coming back as INVALID.

We haven't changed anything.  I looked for posts about other folks having this problem and, unfortunately, I didn't find any.

So I'm posting here to ask if others started experiencing this and, if not, what might be a reason that our system would go from normal to not working without any changes on our end?  I know this is an abstract question;  at this point, it's a rather abstract problem. ;-)

Thanks!

Basic of the PHP connection...

```
   $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
   for ($var = 0; $var < count ($postvars); $var++) {
   $postvar_key = $postvars[$var];
   $postvar_value = $$postvars[$var];
   $req .= "&" . $postvar_key . "=" . urlencode ($postvar_value);
      }

   // post back to PayPal system to validate
   $header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
   $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
   $header .= "Host: www.paypal.com\r\n";
   $header .= "Connection: close\r\n";
   $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen ($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

   $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue on the sandbox enviroment, IPN messages are not being received at all. I checked here for scheduled maintenance https://www.paypal-notify.com/eventnotification/search?eventSearchType=PayPalSiteStatus

but i don't find thing related to IPN notifications.

did you check what the ipn history displays? (https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1046)
In my case there is no http response code even if the notification url is working and reachable from outside.

It is not the first time I experience issues with paypal even if there is no maintenance on going. I suggest you to open a trouble ticket to speed up the resolution

Answer (score 0):

Check your endpoint to be certain you are still sending to the production url (https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-validate) and not the test url. If this checks out you'll need to investigate further to determine what has changed to corrupt your message.

Comment: Think we're headed for the right place.  I just edited my post to add the PHP connection snippet.   Just baffling stuff when something that works stops working and you didn't touch it. ;-)

Comment: Errr... Is really no one else having this problem?  We just got an order that came back as INVALID and when I checked the order inbox for the email, it's not there yet.  They've always been rather instant to appear.  The order is valid, confirmed via PayPal.com.  But there seems to be a delay that's slowing down emails and throwing off IPN.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, and think your web host (HostGator in my case) switched off support for $HTTP_POST_VARS (which is deprecated), so you must now use $_POST

You've not said where you're populating $postvars from but, if like me, you were using PayPal's sample IPN script you were getting it like this:

```
while (list($key, $value) = each($HTTP_POST_VARS)) {
    $postvars[] = $key;
}
```

and needs to be changed to $_POST:

```
while (list($key, $value) = each($_POST)) {
    $postvars[] = $key;
}
```

I then had to change

```
$postvar_value = $$postvars[$var];
```

to

```
$postvar_value = $_POST[$postvar_key];
```